# How do I debug an installed executable created by Visual Studio 2010 (but not in the expected location)?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I've been using CMake for quite some time to generate VS 2008 solutions to build a program, its installer, and its packager (as well as several test programs). In order to run, the program needs several dlls which the install project puts into a bin directory, along with the generated executable. Under VS 2008, if I want to debug the created program, I build the INSTALL project, and then click Debug->Start Debugging. The first time I do this after generating the solution, this presents me with a dialog from which I can browse to the bin folder and then the desired executable.

However, under Visual Studio 2010, after clicking Debug->Start Debugging, I do not get the dialog, but rather get the message that it can't find the ALL_BUILD program (which does not, and should not, exist). I can change the start up project to be the executable in question (or right click on it and choose debug), but then that loads the executable from the wrong path and is therefore unable to find the dlls. I know that I could either add the dlls to my system path or copy the dlls into the same directory where the executable is initially created, but these are less-than-ideal solutions (for testing and portability reasons), and these steps were not required in VS 2008.

This is the exact same CMakeLists.txt file for both cases, and the exact same source code. The only difference is that CMake is run with the "Visual Studio 9 2008" generator in the first case and the "Visual Studio 10" generator in the second case.

I *can* run the generated program from the bin directory using Windows Explorer, but I am not able to debug it (e.g., step through a problem area line-by-line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the debug properties of your start up project so the command line and working directory match your install location.

Comment: Thanks. That seems obvious in hindsight. Unfortunately, I see that CMake is unable to set these values automatically.
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Can_CMake_set_the_Debugging.2FWorking_Directory_property_in_Visual_Studio_projects.3F

Comment: But those settings don't get removed unless you remove your build tree. They will even stay if you wipe your CMake cache.